# Linq and localhost, entity namespace is different than program namespace but still get error

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework, linq, namespaces

I have tried to search for this but every example I find has a problem like them actually having the same namespace as their class or something.

I am simply trying to start using Linq. When I add new item Host is localhost. I have my database in Visualstudio and my project name is different than the DataContext name but I can't get it initialized. I get error:

'LinkedContext' is a namespace but is used like a type'

here is code...

```
namespace TryAgain
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            LinkedContext db = new LinkedContext();
        }
    }
}
```

LinkedContext doesn't work? In settings of the Database Diagram it says the Entity Namespace is 'LinkedContext' So what am I missing. I thought I saw you could run that one line of code to connect your database that is already in VisualStudio due to adding a new item and then start playing with it? I just want to be able to practice with a database! Do stuff like:

```
var example = from x in example.Table
              orderby x.field
              select x;
```

Answer (score 1):

you need `using LinkedContext` at the top of your file. the error you’re getting is telling you `LinkedContext` is a namespace but you’re treating like a type, ie a class. once you define it at the top you can then use the type that you need within that namespace.

Comment: Awesome, That is a huge step in the right directions. Looks like it is working but now I just need to learn how to use Linq! What I entered is returning something weird.

Comment: great glad that helped. now what is your input and what is your expected output?

Comment: var example = from x in db.employees
                          orderby x.employee_id
                          select x;

Comment: after Console.WriteLine(example); I get: SELECT t1.FieldName, t1.FieldName2, etc etc FROM testing( testing is the name of my database).employees t1 ORDER BY t1.employee_id

Answer (score 0):

added "using LinkedContext" to the top of code then also had to use LinkedDataContext not just LinkedContext:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using LinkedContext;

namespace TryAgain
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            LinkedDataContext db = new LinkedDataContext();

            var example = from x in db.employees
                          orderby x.employee_id
                          select x;


            foreach (var whatever in example)
            {        
                Console.WriteLine(whatever.name);
            }
```